# How to get harvard style through "agsm"

Tags: natbib, harvard-style

I wan't to use harvard style in my paper. I'm using TeXMaker and `natbib`. I got `agsm.bst` downloaded. But it's not helping. 
I'm using these commands

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}

\bibliography{FILE}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}  % that loads file agsm.bst 
% it's working fine for \bibliographystyle{plain}, but that's not the referencing I want
\end{document}
```

I doubt it's a problem with the way I'm saving `agsm`.
Can someone help me out?

Comment: In the code given in your post, you are loading the file `pjgsm.bst`, not `agsm.bst`, is this a typo? What error message do you get?

Comment: @Rahul: I've added a comment in your not complete MWE to make clear where you load the file `pjgsm.bst` instead of the wanted `agsm.bst`. Please make always a complete [minimal working example (MWE).](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) I added `\documentclass{article}` to your MWE. Please correct it, if you need something else ...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: @Corentin, i'm sorry, that's a typo, should be {agsm}. Thanks Kurt, you did a perfect editing. But my question still remains unanswered.

Comment: It would help if you could give the error message that you get. Are you sure that the `agsm.bst` file is installed in a location where `bibtex` can find it?

Comment: As you confirmed that `pjgsm` is a typo, I took the liberty of editing your post to replace this with `agsm` as you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was not saving agsm as .bst file, instead it was saved as LATEX style file.